# Extract substring values with multiple key pattern - regex

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract the values **Value1**, **ar online** and **PR** from the following string:

> CN=Value1, OU=ar online, L=PR,

I tried to use the expression *[=][a-zA-z][^\,]+*, but it always return **=Value1**, **=ar online** and **=PR**, and doesn't produce the result I need.

Any tips about how to solve this issue?

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Use a capturing group - `=([a-zA-Z][^,]+)`, or a lookbehind (`(?<==)[a-zA-Z][^,]+`).

Comment: And if you can use capturing groups and the three values always appear in the same order, it's as easy to capture them all at once : `.*CN=([^,]+).*OU=([^,]+).*L=([^,]+)` then refer to the first capturing group for the CN, the second for the OU and the third for the L

Comment: And depending on the regex engine used you can use named capturing groups to improve readability. For instance with python 3 : https://ideone.com/qqsiXI

Comment: Which language are you using? I'm assuming .NET, but you haven't added a language tag, so it's not clear whether or not some regex tokens are available to you (such as lookbehinds)

Comment: I'm using .NET. I didn't add a language tag because I thought it would would not be necessary for this kind of question. (I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow). Anyway, all the given answers worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a *positive look-behind*.

```
(?<=[A-Z]=)[^,]+
```

That will match one or more characters except `,` (greedily), preceded by a letter and `=`.

You can try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/HztchQ/1).